# Crossfire Resets When Lightdm Restarts Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ati, xorg, lightdm, configuration, fglrx

So I had Crossfire running on 14.04, but I decided to update to 15.04 and now it's acting strange. I've gone through the typical steps of commenting out everything in `/etc/init/gpu-manager.conf`, and I've ran through the process of executing:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
sudo aticonfig --adapter=0,1 --cfa
sudo aticonfig --adapter=0,1 --crossfire=on
```

multiple times and each time the Crossfire bridge shows up when I run:

```
aticonfig --lsch
```

However, any time lightdm restarts, either during a reboot or restarting lightdm manually, running `aticonfig --lsch` again returns `No Multiple GPU chains defined`.

I've even gone so far as to replace `/bin/gpu-manager` but even then the problem persists. The issue also doesn't appear to be with the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file because it doesn't get overwritten anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that IOMMU is not enabled.(in bios)
When IOMMU is enabled,after reboot enabled amd crossfire will be disabled.
And kernel will give you message: to enable crossfire ,please disable IOMMU..

```
lspci | grep IOMMU   #output must be noting
```

IOMMU can be switched off in bios ,or with passing iommu=off to kernel.